# Duplicate request is always performed when the request throws an error

Tags: angular, http, angular-httpclient

I have a weird problem.

I have a service, which gets data from the Back-end and a function like this:

```js
  validateChangEmailTokenAndChangeEmail(token: string): Observable<User>
  {
    const callUrl = environment.apiUrl + `users/validate-change-email-token-and-change-email`;
    return this.http.post<User>(callUrl, token, environment.httpOptions)
      .pipe(shareReplay(), retry(0));
  }
```

My problem is that when I subscribe to this observable (which is subscribed only once when a component is initialized) and the BE throws an error, the request will be done one more time. I have tried adding `shareReplay()`, `retry(0)` and `take(1)`. But still no success.

This is my subscription:

```
this.userService.validateChangEmailTokenAndChangeEmail(this.token)
      .subscribe(user => {
       // my logic

      }, error =>
      {
        // handling of error
        this.handleError(error);
      });
```

The function `this.handleError()` will be called **only once**. Which means that the duplicate request is not really taken and processed.

Check the below screenshot. The request error is logged 2 times, the WTF (which comes from `handleError()`) only once.

[image: Errors]

What could it be?

What I have also noticed, is that the subscription will always take the second request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem that I had.

Basically I had implemented a class called `HttpErrorInterceptor` which had a pipe with `retry(1)` inside. That is why each request that resulted in an error was duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a shot in the dark but shareReplay usually keeps the connections even if they're unsubscribed.

Try using

```js
    return this.http.post<User>(callUrl, token, environment.httpOptions)
      .pipe(publishReplay(1), refCount(), retry(0));
```

Comment: No succes with this either, sorry.
Do you think I should change the way I do the requests?
Or keep on researching this problem?

Comment: Not sure. Could you check the network request to see if it's actually 2 POST requests? Maybe one of them is an OPTIONS request

Comment: they are both post requests, since the call goes through to my Back-end, and the corresponding functions are performed.

Answer (score 0):

You are subscribing to that http call more than once.
it's not sharing its emits because calling `validateChangEmailTokenAndChangeEmail()` returns a different observable every time it's invoked.

To achieve what you're after, you actually need to assign that method's result to a local variable and then you can re-subscribe to that local variable over n over.

```
validate$ = this.myService.validateChangEmailTokenAndChangeEmail(this.token);

ngOnInit() {
    this.validate$.subscribe(console.log);
    this.validate$.subscribe(console.log);
}
```

Comment: I have also tried this way, no success. And where am I subscribing more than once?
Thanks

Comment: if you're not subscribing more than once, you don't need `shareReplay`. since you're using it, i'm guessing you are. just incorrectly.